# Display rails join table field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am making an edit page that can edit animals and the owners to that animal. There is a join table involved which contains what Animal belongs to what Owner.

More precisely, Say you have:

```
<% form_for :animal, url: animal_path(@edit_animal), method: :patch do |edit| %>
... animal labels and fields to edit go here ...
    <%= edit.fields_for :owners do |owner| %>
        <%= owner.label :name, "Name" %>
        <%= owner.text_field :name %>
    <%end%>
    <%=edit.submit 'Submit'%>
<%end%>
```

Model Associations:

```
AnimalOwner < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :animal
    belongs_to :owner

Owner < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :animal_owners
    has_many :animals, :through => :animal_owners

Animal < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :animal_owners
    has_many :owners, :through => :animal_owners
```

Basically, I am not sure if I am doing the form correctly for join tables. I also wanted to be able to display the data currently saved in the database using :value, but what how I would do that for a join table?

```
<%= owner.text_field :name, :value => what_goes_here? %>
```

Comment: can you please add the models and their associations properly

Comment: With a simple join table like you are describing you can have an edit form from three different perspectives. From the animals controller/view, owners controller/view and the animal_owners controller/view. It would be fairly clear if the signed in user is the owner and any animal they create they would be the owner of but if an animal can have multiple owners then what does the form look like to create the owner-animal relationship? The edit form would be a simple derivative of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing the Rails way, you don't need to mention the value for existing database data.

```
<%= owner.text_field :name%>
```

This should populate the data to above given field. Also its always better to use a single for for both "new" and "edit" methods. And for "edit" you can also use "PUT" as method type.

---

To use the `field_for` tag, you will also need to tell your `Animal` model that it `accepts_nested_attributes_for :owners`. This will allow the nested params to be massed assigned to the `Animal` instance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Works great!